# How can I avoid counting triplicates as pairs while iterating through an ordered series of letters within an array?

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a simple program to analyze a string to find the word with the greatest amount of duplicate letters within it. It essentially takes a given string, breaks it up into an array of separated words, and then breaks up each separate word into alphabetically sorted groups of individual letters (which are then compared as `prev` and `next`, 2 at a time, as the containing array is iterated through). Any two adjacent and matching values found adds one tally to the hash-file next to the word in question, and the word with the most tallied pairs of duplicate letters is returned at the end as greatest. No matching pairs found in any word returns -1. This is what it's supposed to do.

Below, I've run into a problem: If I don't use a REGEXP to replace one of my matched characters, then my code gives false positives as it will count triplicates (eg, "EEE"), as two separate pairs, (eg, "EEE" = "EE & EE", instead of being viewed as "EE, E"). However, if I DO use the REGEXP below to prevent triplicate counts, then doing so breaks my loop mid-stride, and skips to the next word. Is there no way to make this way work? If not, would it be better to employ a REGEXP which deletes all chars EXCEPT the duplicate characters in question, and then perhaps I could divide the .length of each word by 2 to get the number of pairs remaining? Any ideas as to how to solve this would greatly help.

```
var str = "Helloo aplpplpp pie"; 
//var str = "no repting letrs";
//var str = "ceoderbyte";

function LetterCountI(str) {
    var input = str.split(" ");
    console.log(input);
    console.log("\n")
    var hashObject = {};   
    var word = "";
    var count = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i<input.length; i++) {
        var currentItem = input[i];
        var currentWordIntoChars = currentItem.split("").sort();
        console.log(currentWordIntoChars);
        var counter = 0;

        for(var j=1; j<currentWordIntoChars.length; j++) {
            console.log(currentWordIntoChars[j-1] + "=currentChar j-1");
            console.log(currentWordIntoChars[j] + "=prev j");
            console.log("-");
            var final = currentItem;

            if(currentWordIntoChars[j-1] == currentWordIntoChars[j]) {
                counter++;
                hashObject[final] = counter;
                    //currentWordIntoChars = currentWordIntoChars[j-1].replace(/[a-z]/gi, String.fromCharCode(currentItem.charCodeAt(0)+1));
                //HERE REPLACE j-1 with random# or something
                //to avoid 3 in a row being counted as 2 pair
                //OR use regexp to remove all but pairs, and
                //then divide .length/2 to get pairs.
                console.log(counter + " === # total char pairs");

            }
            if(count<hashObject[currentItem]) {
                word = final;
                count = hashObject[currentItem];
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(hashObject);
    console.log("\n");
    for (var o in hashObject) if (o) return word;
    return -1;

}
console.log(LetterCountI(str));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other way to do it, consists to replace duplicate characters in a sorted word:

```
var str = "Helloo aplpplpp pie"; 

function LetterCountI(str) {

    var input = str.split(" ");
    var count = 0;
    var result = -1;

    for(var i = 0; i<input.length; i++) {
        var nb = 0;
        var sortedItem = input[i].split("").sort().join("");

        sortedItem.replace(/(.)\1/g, function (_) { nb++ });

        if (nb > count) {
            count = nb;
            result = input[i];
        }
    }    

    return result;
}

console.log(LetterCountI(str));
```

**Notes:** The `replace` method is only a way to increment `nb` using a callback function. You can do the same using the `match` method and counting results.

if two words have the same number of duplicates, the first word will be returned by default. You can easily change this behaviour with the condition of the `if` statement.

Comment: This is closest to what I'd asked for. And with additional insights and improvements. Thanks very much for that.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you find a match within a word, increment j by 1 to skip comparing the next letter.

```
var str = "Helloo aplpplpp pie"; 
//var str = "no repting letrs";
//var str = "ceoderbyte";

function LetterCountI(str)
{
  var input = str.split(" ");
  console.log(input);
  console.log("\n")
  var hashObject = {};   
  var word = "";
  var count = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i<input.length; i++)
  {
    var currentItem = input[i];
    var currentWordIntoChars = currentItem.split("").sort();
    console.log(currentWordIntoChars);
    var counter = 0;
    for(var j=1; j<currentWordIntoChars.length; j++)
    {
      console.log(currentWordIntoChars[j-1] + "=currentChar j-1");
      console.log(currentWordIntoChars[j] + "=prev j");
      console.log("-");
      var final = currentItem;
      if(currentWordIntoChars[j-1] == currentWordIntoChars[j])
      {
        counter++;
        hashObject[final] = counter;
        j++; // ADD HERE
        console.log(counter + " === # total char pairs");
      }
      if(count<hashObject[currentItem])
      {
        word = final;
        count = hashObject[currentItem];
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(hashObject);
  console.log("\n");
  for (var o in hashObject) if (o) return word;
  return -1;
}
console.log(LetterCountI(str));
```

Comment: Thank you for the simplest solution. This will be very helpful for me in the future.